# CentOS 8 server computer left open overnight shows a blank screen

Tags: centos

I have a CentOS 8 server computer running apache, ftp and few other servers

I left the computer on over the weekend and now it's not showing me anything on the screen

The computer is on, the monitor is on, I can toggle the keyboard num-lock key LED, the mouse LED is on, I can see the hard drive LED is blinking and I can SSH into the computer through Putty and change Apache configurations

Everything seems to be working, but it's not showing anything on screen. I don't think I have left this computer on for so long before, so I am just guessing that this is the issue. I have left the computer on overnight before and haven't had this issue. This time is has been close to 3-4 days

I have not changed the computer's sleep settings and they should be the default value for Centos8, whatever they are

Normally I would just press a keyboard or mouse button and it would show me the user screen. Right now the screen isn't turning on. What could be happening here, and is there any way to get the display working without forcefully resetting the computer?

Comment: It could have done some updates and not properly restarted. Depending on the design of the computer, it might have overheated. Is the computer room overly warm?  Was there a power event where the computer is?  I leave my own desktop on 24 hours a day and it has been running for 4 years now.   You said, "I can SSH into the computer through Putty"  <-- Can you restart it from your SSH login?  That would be preferable to forcing it off. That would be the last resort.

Answer (score 0):

The screen comes back up again if I remove the HDMI and power connector and reconnect them. Seems to be a bug in CentOS (not sure), but this is what worked for me, aside from restarting the computer through Putty.